# QR decomposition and a change of basis

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, change-of-basis, orthogonal-matrices

Consider a square matrix $A$ and its $QR$ decomposition $A = QR$, where $Q$ is orthogonal and $R$ is upper triangular matrix. Now consider a change of basis. Let
$A' = PAP^T$, where $P$ is an orthogonal matrix. Is there a way how to compute a $QR$ decomposition of $A'$ directly from $Q, R$ and $P$, without actually computing $A'$? In other words, if I know $Q$ and $R$, is there a way how to obtain $Q'$ and $R'$ without actually computing $A'$ and doing $QR$ decomposition?

Answer (score 0):

If $A=QR,$ then $A'=PAP^T=PQRP^T=(PQP^T)(PRP^T).$

The matrix $PQP^T$ is orthogonal. Once you find a decomposition of
$PRP^T=Q'R',$ where $Q'$ is orthogonal and $R'$ is upper triangular, you get
$PAP^T=(PQP^T)Q'R'.$ The matrix $(PQP^T)Q'$ is orthogonal as the product of two orthogonal matrices. In this way knowing $Q$ and $R$ is sufficient for determining
the decomposition of $A'.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I was hoping for a way that would not require to compute a QR decomposition.